# Using Two Tables to give one output

Tags: sql, oracle

### Table: Person

```
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| PersonId    | int     |
| FirstName   | varchar |
| LastName    | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
```

`PersonId` is the primary key column for this table.

### Table: Address

```
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| AddressId   | int     |
| PersonId    | int     |
| City        | varchar |
| State       | varchar |
+-------------+---------+
```

`AddressId` is the primary key column for this table.

Write a SQL query for a report that provides the following information for each person in the `Person` table, regardless if there is an address for each of those people:

```
FirstName, LastName, City, State
```

So this is a pretty straight forward question and my answer is

```
select p.FirstName,p.LastName, a.City, a.State
from Person p , Address a
where p.PersonId = a.PersonId
```

And I'm not getting anything in the output and yes I filled up the tables with some simple lines of data.

Comment: Oracle recommends using [ANSI Join Syntax](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-for-beginners-joins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data would help, but - the way you described it, it looks as if you need **outer join**. Something like this:

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName, a.City, a.State
from Person p left join Address a on a.personid = p.personid
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL query

```
SELECT Person.FirstName, Person.LastName, Address.City, Address.State
FROM Person
LEFT JOIN Address
ON Person.PersonId=Address.PersonId;
```